# How can I define variable array on the laravel blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade, implode

I try like this :

```
<div class="media-body">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    @php $category[] = $category->name @endphp
    @endforeach   
    {{ implode(",", $category) }}
</div>
```

If the code executed, there exist error :

> undefine variable category

How can I solve it?

Comment: You must define `$category[]` with different name outside the `@foreach` loop

Comment: @smokehill, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use Laravel Collection

```
{{ $categories->pluck('name')->implode(', ') }}
```

Or if you wanna do this in foreach then

```
@php ($names = [])

@foreach ($categories as $category)
    @php ($names[] = $category->name)
@endforeach

{{ implode(', ', $names) }}
```

Comment: It does not work. There exist error : `Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute()...`

Comment: I try like this : `<div class="media-body">
    @php ($category = [])
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    @php ($category[] = $category->name)
    @endforeach   
    {{ implode(', ', $category) }}
</div>`

Comment: Now it works. Because before variable array = value of foreach. Both names are the same. That's what caused the error. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare an array within `<?php ... ?>` block and then use the same in a `{{blade}}` block.

Comment: Also, there's the Blade special syntax: `{{--*/ $var = 'test' /*--}}`. Then, you use it in the standard way: `{{ $var }}`.

Comment: @lesssugar, If it is variable array, it does not work